# netbeans setting version php 7.2.12 i

Tags: php, laravel

I tried using spatie/permission and after put code into User class I got an error like this
syntax error, unexpected '$role' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)"

I will add that in editor ( netbeans ) I have setting version of php at 7.0 and version installed on laptop is 7.2.12 . Path to composer in netbeans is 
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat

In this way it looks like my class User

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use  HasRoles;

    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'writer']);
    $permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'edit articles']);
}
```

Comment: Where is problem ?

Comment: Why did you set NB to 7.0 and not to your installed PHP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your PHP version the problem is You can not call a method to set a default value for a variable in PHP.

These two lines should use in a controller or a console:

```
     $role = Role::create(['name' => 'writer']);
     $permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'edit articles']);
```

This Tutorial explains what should you do [patie Laravel Permission Package Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIgYJlu03bI)